# Can I turn on some setting to make typedoc infer types as well as the VS code?

Tags: typescript, documentation, typedoc

I have this method somewhere in my code:

```
public async createProject() {
    let req = new requests.CreateProjectRequest(this.newTransactionId(), this.connection!, this.defaultMaxWaitForResponse)
    return await req.run();
}
```

When I hover over the method name in VS Code I can see the return value of the method. I actually don't know who is responsible for the annotation I see in the tooltip. Does VS Code have a TypeScript server running in the background or is it doing its own thing? Anyway I see that:

```
(method) Client.createProject(): Promise<requests.CreateProjectResponse>
```

But in the docs I generate using TypeDoc I only see the much more generic:

```
createProject(): Promise<object>
```

I want more specific docs, but I also don't want to add unnecessary annotations where TypeScript/VS Code can already infer the correct types.

Can I turn on some setting to make typedoc infer types as well as the VS code?

**EDIT**

Example of return type that shows up as only `Promise<object[]>`.

```
export type ArcGetSuppliesResponse = Array<{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    manufacturer?: string;
    model?: string;
}>;
```

Comment: Do you have the [`--includeDeclarations`](https://typedoc.org/guides/arguments/#includedeclarations) option enabled?

Comment: @Chic: That didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I don't think I did.